# How to install the Shapely package in Python

Tags: python

Has anybody managed to install the Shapely package in Python ?

I tried downloading the file from here (https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely)

and then running the command below but I get the following error message :  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64

Im working with Python 3.7 and a 64 bits Windows machine so I dont know what the problem is.

```
pip install Shapely‑1.6.4.post2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Is your Python 3.7 also x64? You can see this from the banner that's printed if you run `python`.

Comment: Yes I am: Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after ugrading pip (python -m pip install --upgrade pip) it is possible to install Shapely